# What does given filed mean in netstat -s on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, ip, icmp

I am analyzing the the output of `netstat -s` and wanted to know what *"input ICMP message failed"* is meant for. Below is output of `netstat -s`,

```
Icmp: 
      643 ICMP messages received 
      0 input ICMP message failed. 
      ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 450 
        echo requests: 9 
        echo replies: 2 
      102 ICMP messages sent 
      0 ICMP messages failed 
      ICMP output histogram: 
        destination unreachable: 84 
        echo request: 9 
        echo replies: 9

 Icmp:
    648 ICMP messages received
    0 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
      destination unreachable: 450
      echo requests: 14
      echo replies: 2
    107 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
      destination unreachable: 84
      echo request: 9
      echo replies: 14
```

How is the value 0 is assigned to *"input ICMP message failed"* and in which condition value other than zero is assigned to this field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's defined in RFC 4293 - [Management Information Base (MIB) for the Internet Protocol (IP)](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc4293.txt): (page 82)

> icmpStatsInErrors: The number of ICMP messages that the entity (host) received but determined as having ICMP-specific errors (bad ICMP checksums, bad length, etc.).

---

How I found that out?

`netstat` will get it's information from the kernel, from `/proc/net/snmp`. It just formats it. You can see that in the [source code of `netstat`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/files/?source=navbar).

So I had a look into the related kernel code which writes the /proc file. It's: [net/ipv4/proc.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/proc.c) (line: 338) You can see that the constant `ICMP_MIB_INERRORS` is used what tells me, that the kernel is implementing the ICMP [MIB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Management_information_base) for [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snmp) purposes.

I've googled for that MIB and found [RFC 4293](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/rfc/rfc4293.txt). On page 82 you'll find the definition for `icmpStatsInErrors` what is the value in question.

Open source rules! ;)

Comment: You can download this C program: https://eval.in/42867 .. It sends a an icmp echo paket with a bad checksum. You can verify this using `netstat -s` after calling it. Compile it with gcc and execute it as root.

Comment: Thanks @hel2mgl for such nice answer ,I have downloaded  the program you mentioned ,compiled and execute(o/p is Index for interface eth0 is 2) but the value of "input ICMP message failed" is still zero.Could you please let me know the whole  procedure in detail.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar I missed to tell you that you'll have to change the IP's in the porgram

Comment: Thanks you very much @hek2mgl ,I am able to increment this field ,Earlier i was trying on same machine but now I used two different machine and able to see the change

Comment: yeah, I've used 127.0.0.1 as source IP and my outer IP address as target

Comment: One thing would like to know from your end,which part of code is responsible for incrementing this counter for "input ICMP message failed".Is there any way to tell that code that is taking care of this counter is not working well.

Comment: No, this code just sends an ICMP ping paket with a wrong checksum. Check the I made a comment starting with `!!!` nearly to the bottom. The kernel of the target box increments the counter. Why do you need this?

Comment: Sorry @hek2mgl I should have asked which part of kernel code take care of incrementing this filed. I am working on one issue where this filed is not getting incremented after getting the wrong ICMP message .This is customized kernel based on ARM linux.Could you please again redirect me to right location in kernel where this increment happens

Comment: I don't know which file exactly is doing this. But it's in net/... Have you analyzed the ICMP paket in wireshark? does it show up as *corrupted* in wireshark as well? In which way the paket is wrong? (checksum, length, ... ?)

Comment: I have not analyzed the ICMP packet yet ,still I have to send the ICMP packet to target that you have given.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35344/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-amit-singh-tomar)